# What are the two sensors doing in the automatic bread production line?

Tags: sensor, electrical, electric-machine, function, sensing

I want to know what is the name of these 2 sensors and what function they perform

[image: Sensor 1 Picture 1]
[image: Sensor 1 Picture 2]

[image: Sensor 2 Picture 1]
[image: Sensor 2 Picture 2]

Some of you were complaining about the picture quality. It is the highest quality image I can get. Also these sensors were used in a bread making factory. Link is https://youtu.be/xM7tkREK2IE. Sensor 1 at 1:11 and Sensor 2 at 5:02 . Now please answer my question.

Comment: We need better images, one is out of focus. Normally these would be object detectors using infra-red light or magnetic detection. It would help to know what products they have to count.

Comment: There's insufficient data (only blurred photographs) in your question, to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: Oh my goodness, is it a ninja level spy job interview? I would say Sensor 1 is a light sensor for the smart curtain, and Sensor 2 is an IR sensor. My answers are of course nonsense, but in order to go to second round, I need to give answesr to impress the panel that I am making brainstorming curious judgments (without cursing the stupid panel showing me blurred pictures). Of course it is the spy's job to find out more clues from blurred pictures. That is what a spy is  for. :)

Comment: the clarity of the pictures is irrelevant ... the question is nonsense ... the question is similar to showing a picture of a cardboard box and asking what is inside the box

Comment: @jsotola That would be like Schrodinger's cat? Are these sensors counting cats?

Comment: I have updated the question with better photos and also provided the YouTube video link with spefic time when the 2 sensors appears. So please answer the question.

Comment: @Karan Srivastava, I confess me IQ 97 failed your ninja grade interview. Now I want to try by best on the junior grade exam. My answer: (1) Sensor 1 is a remote IR temperature sensor, to check the surface temperature of the baked stuff. (2) Senor 2 is an IR reflective senor, to detect and count the little guys passing on. Let me see if I can use google image to find out the models of the two sensors. Any time limit for this second round interview, Sir?

Comment: I am not rude . Answer the question if you know

Comment: @tlfong01, Sensor 1 is not a IR temperature sensor for sure because it is sensing the dough balls (see the video please, I have provided it for this purpose only , use it)

Comment: Sensor 1 is a dough ball sensor

Comment: @jsotola What do you mean by Dough Ball sensor . Please watch the video if you are not getting the picture right and answer the question 

Comment: @KaranSrivastava you said that sensor 1 is sensing dough balls, that makes it a dough ball sensor ... sensor 2 is a dough tray sensor

Comment: But there does not exist a sensor called dough ball sensor . Also I think both sensor are counting the no of object passed so in my opinion it is object counting sensor and not a dough ball sensor 

Comment: you asked for the `name` of the sensor ... the name would be whatever the manufacturer of the machine chooses to call it ... it could be `sensor 1` or `s1` or `s_ball` ... i suggest that you contact the manufacturer and ask

Comment: @Karan Srivastava stop being rude, this website is a community helping for free, you shouldnt keep saying answer the question when the data your are providing is so stupidly low quality and almost useless.

Answer (score 7):

***Question***

*What the two sensors over there are up to?  Can I know their names, Mr Ninja?*

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Answer***

***Short Answer***

*Part A - What the two sensors are up to?*

The sensors look like those cheap infrared detectors hobbyists use for obstacle avoidance toy cars (Refs 5, 6).

However, unlike the bread production line application, the obstacle toy cars to avoid usually has a smooth surface to reflective light.  ***But in this auto bread production line appliciation, detector is not moving, but obstacle is***.

In this automatic bread production line application, the bread should not reflect light that well, so the typical trick is to place a stainless plate at the back of the obstacle to reflect light.  Now the obstacle (bread) passes by will absorb the light, and so stope reflection.  In other words, reflection stops means another bread arrives.

---

[image: ir reflector]

*1.  Sensor 1*

Sensor 1 blinks Green when no bread in sight.  Blinks Yellow as soon as bread comes up.  So I guess it is a bread detector.  Of course the yellow LED can be read by another smart guy to count and record.

[image: sensor 1]

---

*2. Sensor 2*

In the same video, Sensor 2 is not blinking at all.  I think, similar to Sensor 1 above, reflection get interrupted means bread (in this case, another tray of bread arrives.

Of course the bread detector might be sophisticated enough to also measure temperature and do data recording etc, or even fancier do something below: If the bread surface is not hot enough to stick the sesames, hold on the tray for a little bit longer, at the same time blow hot air on it, before moving on for the rain of sesames.

This is only my wild guess.  After watching the videos, I have the feeling that the auto bread system is actually very low tech, and high precision position and timing is not at all required.

I would think that there is not any MCU, not to mention SBC, is used in the whole bread production plant.  The CNC like digital controlled oven might only need one Celius degree and one second timing accuracy.

As can be seen in the video, the oven does not seem to have any data record/database, everything is open loop and ready reporting.  In other words, no   feedback control.  (I once talked to a barbabe pork and roast oven chef and found that the oven is sort of a microwave oven, you can set time and temperature, but the meat temperature is measured by a thermometer.  In other words, all manual controlled by the chef.  He would LOL if I suggest an Arduino and Raspberry Pi IoT oven.

[image: sensor 2]

/ to continue, ...

---

*Part B - What are the name of the sensors?*

I guess the OP is curious to do what those sensors are for, or their "names", not model or part number.  As mentioned earlier, the sensor can be hobbyist level cheapy, low precision infra red reflective sensors.  I have played with them in my Arduino days.  I found them friendly for newbies.  Of course the OP can upgrade to ultrasound or even laser sensors with cm accuracy, but of course, as I guessed, centimetre accuracy is an over kill, toy grade accuracy is "appropriate" technology.

/ to continue, ...

---

*Part C - Discussion, conclusion, and Recommendation*

*Discussion*

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*Conclusion*

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*Recommendation*

As I said earlier, the cheapy US$1 IR Reflective Sensor is hobbyist friendly, educational, and great fun.  I would recommend the OP and other newbies to play with it.  There are many good references out there, one of which is the following:

[TCRT5000 IR Reflective Sensor - ProtoSupplies, US$1](https://protosupplies.com/product/tcrt5000-ir-reflective-optical-sensor/)

---

[image: IR Reflective Sensor]

*/ to continue, ...*

---

/ to continue, ...

---

***Long Answer***

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [About Ozkoseoglu Group - www.ozkoseoglu.com](http://ozkoseoglugrup.com/en/companies-industry.html)

(2) [ÖZKÖSEOĞLU Full Automatic Bread Tunnel Oven Production Line - 2014jul14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bce6D6ChZHs)

(3) [OZKOSEOGLU Steam Pipe oven - 2017dec05](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btUadRwm-7Y)

(4) [ÖZKÖSEOĞLU Gold Series Oven - 2017Apr11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn0nOLUsFx4)

(5) [AliExpress TCRT5000L IR Reflective Infrared LED Sensor Switches - US$3](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32372527492.html?)

(6) [AliExpress Infrared Obstacle Avoidance Photocell Proximity Switch 3-80cm Detection - US$2](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/33004897150.html?)

(7) [TCRT5000 IR Reflective Sensor Module - ProtoSupplies, US$1](https://protosupplies.com/product/tcrt5000-ir-reflective-optical-sensor/)

(8) [TCRT500 IR Reflection Module - AliExpress US$1](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32871499245.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.c88c469dwi033m&algo_pvid=06195d9b-f1ce-466e-b351-c1768a62d08a&algo_expid=06195d9b-f1ce-466e-b351-c1768a62d08a-14&btsid=0ab6fb8315967933752248655e06b5&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

(9) [TCRT5000 Vishay, Reflective Sensor Module Product Sheet - RS](https://hken.rs-online.com/web/p/reflective-optical-sensors/9190001?cm_mmc=HK-PPC-DS3A-_-google-_-3_HK_EN_Reflective%20Optical%20Sensors_Vishay_BMM-_-Vishay%20-%20Reflective%20Optical%20Sensors%20-%209190001-_-%2Btcrt5000&matchtype=b&kwd-307259190187&gclid=Cj0KCQjw6575BRCQARIsAMp-ksNURsI4y815vsp6YlRjslyIW5iQWeE64xbQsdR8JQnGOJvbLZyD5boaAjYUEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

(10) [TCRT5000 Reflective Sensor Datasheet - Vishay](https://docs.rs-online.com/4e18/0900766b814ae506.pdf)

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - ÖZKÖSEOĞLU Auto Bread Oven YouTube Screen Capture*

[image: auto bread 1]

---

[image: auto bread 2]

---

[image: auto bread 3]

---

[image: auto bread 4]

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*End of Answer*

Comment: You forgot to write an answer.

Comment: @StarCat, many thanks for your reminder. So I have added something. Ah, Sunday afternoon locking up tea time. See you later.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Since dough is not made of metal (Lets hope not) only a motion detector with close-proximity detection would work dependably. The mass and size of the blob of dough would be easy to pick up and feed to product counting software.

The other sensor seems more primitive and could use the reflective light to count empty dough pans or simply inform the software that pans are ready for new batches of dough. These sensors are part of a simple servo-loop that provides basic automation.

So no one has to stand there and count batches of dough, and when the batch is done and it is time to produce a new batch. The fancy computers keep track of all the metrics. They compare what is made to what is required.